# Control cannot fall through from one case label (case "Juventus":') to another. Any idea why?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I am retrieving Control cannot fall through from one case labe (case "Juventus":') to another. Any idea why? I am trying to open a different form to print based on the result of the query. Thanks

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=Marketing;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select [Team] from baf where id=(select max(id) from baf)", connection);
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (read.Read())
    {
        String AAA = (read["Team"].ToString());
        switch (AAA)
        {
            case "Arsenal":
                Print dd = new Print();
                dd.Show();
                break;
            case "Juventus":
                Print2 dd2 = new Print2();
                dd2.Show();
            case "Porto":
                Print3 dd3 = new Print3();
                dd3.Show();
                break;
            case "Bayern Munich":
                Print4 dd4 = new Print4();
                dd4.Show();
                break;
            }
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've missed the `break` statement in the `case "Juventus":`

Comment: 8 questions and **not a single** accepted answer. You could really return the favour for the people who helped you. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) might help if you don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike C or C++, C# does not allow `switch/case` statements where the control flow can "fall through" from one `case` into the next.

In c, this would work

```
switch(i)
{
    case 1: printf("1");
    case 2: printf("1 or 2"); break;
}
```

and it would print `1` **and** `1 or 2` if `i` was 1, but only `1 or 2` if `i` was 2.

In c#, this is not allowed. Every non-empty `case` must exit the whole `switch` statement. This can either be done by

- `break`
- `return`
- `throw` or even
- `goto`

So you're missing the `break` statement at your `case "Juventus"`:

```
case "Juventus":
    Print2 dd2 = new Print2();
    dd2.Show();
    break; // you forgot that
```

---

Edit: as others mentioned, *empty* case statements are allowed to fall through:

```
switch(i)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
        // do something if i is 1 or 2
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thorough answer. However `goto` is not recommended nowadays.

Comment: The control flow can fall through if the case does not contain any commands to execute.

Comment: This is not 100% correct. While you are correct in the above, cases can fall through if there are no code in the case block itself.

Answer (score 0):

add break; before statement

```
case "porto":
```